How to create a cancel button
<div id="modalBackdrop"
                        class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50 hidden flex items-center justify-center z-50">
                        <!-- Modal Content -->
                        <div class="bg-white rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-lg max-w-md w-full dark:bg-gray-800">
                            <div class="p-4 border-b dark:border-gray-700">
                                <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-800 dark:text-gray-200">New Folder</h2>
                            </div>
                            <form action="{{ route('folder.create') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-full">
                                    <input type="text" id="default-input" name="folder_name"
                                        class="mr-2 ml-2 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500">
                                </div>
                                <div class="p-4 border-t flex justify-end dark:border-gray-700">
                                    <button type="submit"
                                        class="px-4 py-2 bg-green-600 text-white rounded-md mr-2">Submit</button>
                                    <button id="closeModalBtn"
                                        class="px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 text-white rounded-md">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

Because the cancel button is in the same form with the submit button so when I click on cancel it will active form. Anyone has any suggest for this button? Thanks!
Because the cancel button is in the modal so I try using the url()->previous() but it will return to the page I access before not close the modal.

Try to set type="button" with closeModalBtn and it will not active form

Use type=button it will not submit your form and you can manage your onclick event with your specified identifier.
<button type="button" id="closeModalBtn" class="px-4 py-2 bg-red-600 text-white rounded-md">Close</button>


Oh I see! Thanks ^^
